# How to query to get the last updated date in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this mongodb collection. There is two `file1.pkg` with different `lastUpdate` date.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("550286416fee741b0379c2d8"),
    "lastUpdate" : ISODate("2015-03-12T16:00:00.000Z"),
    "file" : "file1.pkg",
    "idBook" : "54f6d1d8c239491400aa495e",
    "idUser" : "54c83f37e2e315bfbb43e98a"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("450286416fee741e0379c2d8"),
    "lastUpdate" : ISODate("2015-03-10T16:00:00.000Z"),
    "file" : "file1.pkg",
    "idBook" : "54f6d1d8c239491400aa495e",
    "idUser" : "54c83f37e2e315bfbb43e98a",
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("560286416fee741b0379c24d"),
    "lastUpdate" : ISODate("2015-03-12T16:00:00.000Z"),
    "file" : "file2.pkg",
    "idBook" : "54f6d1d8c239491400aa495e",
    "idUser" : "54c83f37e2e315bfbb43e98a"
}
```

I want to get file with latest updated date like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("550286416fee741b0379c2d8"),
    "lastUpdate" : ISODate("2015-03-12T16:00:00.000Z"),
    "file" : "file1.pkg",
    "idBook" : "54f6d1d8c239491400aa495e",
    "idUser" : "54c83f37e2e315bfbb43e98a"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("560286416fee741b0379c24d"),
    "lastUpdate" : ISODate("2015-03-12T16:00:00.000Z"),
    "file" : "file2.pkg",
    "idBook" : "54f6d1d8c239491400aa495e",
    "idUser" : "54c83f37e2e315bfbb43e98a"
}
```

How can I  query in **Mongoose** to get such result? I am new to Mongoose and MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to do this:

```
MyModel.aggregate([
    // Sort the docs by lastUpdate descending to put the newest ones first.
    {$sort: {lastUpdate: -1}},
    // Group on file, taking the first (newest) doc for each file name.
    {$group: {
        _id: '$file',
        doc: {$first: '$$ROOT'}
    }}
], function(err, docs) {
    // Reshape the docs array into just the docs.
    docs = docs.map(function(doc) {
        return doc.doc;
    });
    // docs contains your desired result
})
```